# October CMS: User extended module throw an error

Tags: php, laravel, octobercms, octobercms-plugins

I have installed OCtoberCMS, and use [User Extended plugin](https://octobercms.com/plugin/clake-userextended) to make a profile page.

[image: component]

When i try to use component to show Friends reques, the page throws me an error

> Call to a member function take() on array

[image: the error]

Here is the function:

```
public static function listReceivedFriendRequests($limit = 5)
{
    $users = new Collection();
    
    $limit = Helpers::unlimited($limit);
    
    $requests = Friend::friendRequests()->take($limit);
    
    foreach ($requests as $user) {
        $users->push(UserUtil::getRainlabUser($user->user_that_sent_request));
    }
    return $users;
}
```

This happened when user never has an friend request. Onece if they have a friend request this error not show anymore. How can I fix it?

Comment: it is possible that for no values `friendRequests()` static function initialises a empty array & passed to it, thus this error, try to do `dd(Friend::friendRequests())` to see whats inside when  user never has an friend request

Comment: @bhucho When I try this shows on user that previously has an friend request **Collection {#1653 ▼
  #items: []
}**

But on page that`s throw the error just []

Answer (score 0):

I just tested and make couple of changes. For now is work good, but don`t know is this the best way to do this :D

```
     public static function listReceivedFriendRequests($limit = 5)
    {
        $users = new Collection();

        $limit = Helpers::unlimited($limit);

$requests = Friend::friendRequests();
        if(!empty($requests))
        {
            $requests = Friend::friendRequests()->take($limit);
        }
         

        foreach ($requests as $user) {
            $users->push(UserUtil::getRainlabUser($user->user_that_sent_request));
        }
        return $users;
    }
```